# Can't launch Pantheon Files from terminal

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-files

Just installed Juno today and for some reason neither `pantheon-files` nor `sudo pantheon-files-pkexec` work anymore. Does anyone know how one can launch pantheon-files through the terminal now? Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The required commands are now `io.elementary.files` and `io.elementary.files-pkexec`.

The native apps are being moved to the *io.elementary* namespace to avoid ambiguities.